# Extracting substring from a given string using REGEX

Tags: java, regex

```
String s="For the AWSDataTransfer product, this is the public pricing plan";
```

How do I extract `AWSDataTransfer` (word between `the` and `product`) using REGEX in JDK?

Comment: Will it always be the third word?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a website where you ask for people to do your work and write your code for you. If you have a specific problem, we are happy to help you with where you're stuck. So show some effort and post some code you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: @m.buettner what if someone needs an idea to do some effort? like in this case, if you don't know how to use Regex, you can't write code to extract substrings, so maybe we can just show them how to do it, not write their code for them

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
String s="For the AWSDataTransfer product, this is the public pricing plan";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("the\\s(.+?)\\sproduct");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
AWSDataTransfer
```